# Create Subclass and after super() call remove unnecessary items from parent

Tags: java, android, oop, inheritance

I have in my app 2 bars : `topBar`, `bottomBar`.

Basically each one of them creates images and set there positions on the screen. in my app I added a new screen that suppose to be with different bar - `Advanced`, but with some identical logic.

```
public class TopBar {

public TopBar () {
initImageA();
initImageB();
initResultManager();
initBG();
initLines()
}

}

public class BottomBar {

public BottomBar () {
initBg();
initBox();
initCover();
initcolorsLine();
initMenu()
}

}
```

In my app I crate bar according to the state:

```
private TopBar mTopBar;
private Bottom mBottomBar;

if (mState == "normal"){
   mTopBar = new TopBar();
   mBottomBar = new Bottom();
}

else {
    mTopBar = new AdvancedTopBar();
    mBottomBar = new AdvancedBottomBar();
}

mTopBar.setTitle()
mTopBar.setMainImage();
mBottomBar.drawLines()
.
.
.
```

AdvancedTopBar

```
    public class AdvancedTopBar extends TopBar {

        public AdvancedTopBar () {
         super();
         removeImageA();
         removeImageB();
         removeResultManager();
         removeBG();
         removeLines();

    }

    private removeImageA() {
    .
    .
    .
    }
}
```

Is it the right way to use inherence for creating the `AdvancedTopBar` for some identical logic (3,4 members) and calling to parent `super()` whats triggers initializing of images and then I just remove them one by one and create my own images, I think it's wrong... what options do I have to use different types of bars by on instance?

Comment: That would be an indication that you shouldn't be using inheritance at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just one of the many possible approaches: have one class and pass a boolean switch value in the constructor.

```
public class TopBar {

    public TopBar(boolean advanced) {
        doCommonStuff();
        if (advanced) {
            doAdvancedStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

So `new TopBar(true)` will give you an advanced bar, `new TopBar(false)` a standard one.